# Change the marker symbol image to vertical line in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to replace the image with simple LINE[Vertical Line] to highlight highest point or point on the chart?

[HighChart with symbol(image) as the marker](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-symbols/gray)

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is using highcharts plotlines:

```
 plotLines: [{
            color: '#FF0000',
            width: 2,
            value: 7
        }]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xDVTJ/

In this case, the plotLine is on the xAxis, which makes it vertical. I've specified a value of 7, which puts it on category number 7 (starting at 0).

Comment: :-) As, the data which are loaded to chart are dynamic(x and y axis) and moreover I wanted to replace the image to VERTICAL LINE...

Comment: I don't understand what you want

Comment: So you would like to have marker with line? IF yes I'm not sure where the problem is with your example, which use image. Only what you need is add "line" marker as image and adapt width/height. Better solution is introduced by SteveP, but I'm not sure what is wrong with it.

Comment: As I have to plot the line based on the timestamp which occurs on x-axis. So, manually giving the value to plotlines won't help me much. In DATA option we have marker(option) which gets the image on the chart when that the particular timestamp value dynamically occurs. So, I want to replace the marker image with the vertical line.

Comment: Plot lines can be added and removed dynamically, just like data. If you post some code, we can show you how.

Comment: @SteveP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036908/correctly-plot-the-x-axis-on-given-milliseconds-value-using-highcharts