# Display the Plotted value on x axis using highcharts

Tags: highcharts

How to display the plotted value correctly to the exact milliseconds on the chart? How place a point or tooltip to exact milliseconds?

```
 xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        plotLines: [{
            color: '#FF0000',
            width: 2,
            value: 1366113390066
        }]

    }
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/santoshgiridhar/75PzT/5/)

Comment: increase the width  chart: {}

Answer (score 2):

Your series is not showing because your data array is not in a usable format.

this:

```
data: [{
                'value': 731,
                    'timestamp': 1366032438641
            }
```

should be either
this:

```
data: [{
  'x': 1366032438641,
  'y': 731
}
```

or, more simply, this:

```
data: [[1366032438641,731]]
```

reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data

You'll have to clarify what you mean about the other part of your question.

EDIT:{

If you want actual millisecond precision, you will have to have enough width in your chart to specify a pixel per millisecond.  This is not going to happen in any real chart obviously.

There's no way to draw a 2 pixel wide line in a ~600 pixel wide chart displaying 20+ hours and have it be precise to a millisecond.

That's about 72 million milliseconds in 600 pixels, which works out to 0.0000083 pixels per millisecond...  (or 120,000 milliseconds per pixel)

:)

Comment: I have updated my question and the link...thank you for the solution related to series I just misplaced the array.

Comment: I think you'll still need to further clarify.  What about your current solution is not working as you would like?  Answer updated to reflect new info